# Loop through files, split text and save the files

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have some vba code which loops through all csv-files in a folder. It saves a file but does not split text into columns.

When I step through the code using F8, I can see that the text is split to columns, but when reopening the modified file I can't see the text having been split.

I am trying to open each file, split text to columns, and then save and go to the next file. I want to this for all files in a folder of my choice. Each folder may contain thousands of files.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()
'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Change First Worksheet's Background Fill Blue
      wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Select

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        "|", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
        Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1) _
        , Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array( _
        19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A1").Select

    'Save and Close Workbook
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to explicitly define the destination, with a workbook and worksheet, here: `Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1")` as `wb.worksheets(1).Range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

You may be saving the file back to csv. You should save the file in xlsx, this way:

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=split(myfile, ".")(0), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

And please apply @Luuklag's suggestion, too.